# Org-mode navigate in list

Tags: org-mode, navigation

How to navigate in same level list, with sub list in between?

```
- one (cursor at the beginning)
  - two
    - three
- four (move to this list)
```

Tried `C-up` and `M-a`, but they go through each sub level, instead of jumping directly to next same level list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>M-x org-next-item</kbd> and <kbd>M-x org-previous-item</kbd> work like this: they move point to the next (or previous) list item at the same level.

You can bind them to keys if you want - e.g. <kbd>C-c n</kbd> and <kbd>C-c p</kbd> are not used in the Org mode keymap by default, so you might want to use them for this:

```el
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c n") #'org-next-item)
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c p") #'org-previous-item)
```